# How to create "mile markers" on route map and/or "kilometer split/pace" chart in a Google Fit session summary?

Tags: google-fit

I have created a python script that is able to connect to Google Fit, create an activity, upload datapoints and create a "session" based on activity data that I am extracting from Huawei Health via HiTrack files.

However, the sessions that I am creating do not show "mile markers" on the route map, nor does it show each kilometer time split in the "speed" summary, like the ones shown on "automatically tracked" sessions.

For instance, here are the map and "speed" section from an "automatically tracked" cycle session (ie. the phone in my backpack detected I was out cycling and recorded this data):

- [Map with "mile markers"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhsKL.jpg)
- [Speed section showing kilometer "splits"/pace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6xmT.png)

However, after uploading data using my script, I get this:

- ["Map with no markers"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3Swm.png)
- ["Speed section with no splits or pace info"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53iex.png)

Is there a particular datatype or datapoint record that I need to be inserting to get these "mile markers" to show on the map?

And is there a particular datatype or datapoint record that I need to be inserting to get the kilometer splits/pace records to show in the "speed" section?